# iterate randomly over a group of numbers based on one condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi let me illustrate my problem with an example:

I have a dataframe df with a column called NorD.

and chunks of numbers (deviants and neutrals):

Deviants:

```
24, 13, 24

13, 24, 13
```

Neutral:

```
24, 24, 24



NorD

 N
 N
 N
 D
 N
 D
 N
 D
 N
 D
```

What I am trying to do is create 3 columns: respectively "N" , "Size", "Spacing" and fill it with one of the chunk of deviants, chosen randomly in the available deviant chunks, when the column "NorD" == "D", however when one chunk of the deviant has been used to fill a D twice it can't be used again (so each deviant can only appear twice in the whole dataframe).

when "NorD" == N fill it with the neutral chuck (24, 24, 24).

Desired result:

```
NorD N Size Spacing

 N   24  24    24
 N   24  24    24
 N   24  24    24
 D   24  13    24
 N   24  24    24
 D   13  24    13
 N   24  24    24
 D   13  24    13
 N   24  24    24
 D   24  13    24
```

This is what I have now for a dataframe with 240 rows:

```
df["NorD"] = is already imported so no need to care about this just need to know the column exist

df["N"] = np.nan
df["Size"] = np.nan
df["Spacing"] = np.nan
```

Stuck 1 #What I am trying to do is fill my second third and fourth row with 24 24 24 when the first row is equal to N but this code doesn't work =>

```
for i in range(240):
        if ['NorD'] == 'N':
            df.loc[i] = ['24','24','24']
```

Stuck 2: I don't even know how to approach this problem Fill twice and only twice the following numbers if you encounter 'D' in the second third and fourth column.=>

```
for i in range(240):
    if ['NorD'] == 'D':

        ##from here it is psuedocode 


13,13,24
13,24,13
24,24,13
etc (there are 48 d 24 chunks so each deviant chunk should appear twice)
```

UPDATE:
Stuck 1 has been solved with this code:

```
for i in range(240):
    if df.loc[i,'NorD'] == 'N':
        df.loc[i,'N'] = 24
        df.loc[i,'Size'] = 24
        df.loc[i,'Space'] = 24
```

Still trying to solve stuck 2

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And what's the difference between a "chunk" and a "chuck"?

Comment: @PaulCornelius typo it is supposed to be chunk, I have tried to loop over a list based on a condition NorD == D fill with deviant else fill with 24, 24, 24 but that did not work got a bunch of errors as I am new to pandas coming from R. I manage it in R but not in python so I am trying to learn by putting code side by side.

Comment: I doubt if anyone will write the whole program for you from scratch.  If you posted some code along with the errors you got, there is a much better chance that someone will read it and give some useful suggestions.

Comment: Yes will do let me clean it up :)

Comment: I hope this is more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question. Got some help on pydev slack thank you jkelly:

```
# You made the initial df above from random import shuffle

a_list_of_b_values = 
[   {       'N': 1,         'Size': 2,      'Space': 3  },
{       'N': 1,         'Size': 2,      'Space': 3  }, 
{       'N': 2,         'Size': 3,      'Space': 4  },  
{       'N': 2,         'Size': 3,      'Space': 4  },etc ...]
```

## This ... means enumerate all the necessary values twice

```
shuffle(a_list_of_b_values)

for i in range(240):
    if df.loc[i,'SorD'] == 'S':
        df.loc[i,'N'] = 24
        df.loc[i,'Size'] = 24
        df.loc[i,'Space'] = 24  

    elif d.loc[i, 'SorD'] == 'D':       
        data = a_list_of_b_values.pop()         
        df.loc[i,'N'] = data['N']
        df.loc[i,'Size'] = data['Size']
        df.loc[i,'Space'] = data['Space']
```